# Can't Find ListOjbect Table within a Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

`Worksheets("PivotDataSheet").ListObjects("tabletest").Range.Select`

The code above cannot find the listobject "tabletest" within the worksheet "PivotDataSheet". I have tried to access the listobject as an index with no luck. I always get 'Run-time error 9: Subscript out of Range'.
This should be a simple fix, and I've been coding VBA for years, however I have no idea why now I can't access a ListObject. The tabletest exists as a table already in the sheet("PivotDataSheet").

Am I missing something? Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you

[image: See photo below for table and sheet name]

Comment: That suggests that you don't have such a table on that sheet. Double check the name.

Comment: You are sure that the sheet is on the *Active* workbook? BWT: You can select it only if the sheet is active (else you'll get runtime error 1004). Not talking about the fact that you likely don't need to select something at all...

Comment: Your picture looks more like a named range than a table.

Comment: Thanks SJR and FunThomas for your quick responses. I've attached a screenshot of the "tabletest" and verified I'm on the "PivotDataSheet".

Comment: SJR that's very very true....thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As *SJR* guessed in the comments, you probably don't have a table but a named range. If you need a table instead, just mark the range and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to convert the range to a table. If it is okay to deal with a named range, you can use

```
Worksheets("PivotDataSheet").Range("tabletest").Select
```